# Bootstrap4, How to limit the height of a scrollable column to the height of a responsive embed column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 layout with 3 columns, the middle column has two nested columns. One is an embeded youtube video with responsive size and the other is a list of text with a scroll bar. I want to set the height of the scrollable column (the red background) to exactly the height of the embeded responsive video and make it resizable and responsive, in case the device width is insuficient it should be collapsed bellow the video. The code is here https://jsfiddle.net/h7f8r1ut/

Please suggest if this can be achieved without javascript code.

I've looked at similar questions but was unable to find a suitable solution for my exact requirements.

```css
.scroll {
  text-align: left;
  height: 40vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-2 bg-dark text-info">
        left sidebar
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 bg-secondary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-10" id="video">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 scroll bg-danger">
              <p>1</p>
              <p>2</p>
              <p>3</p>
              <p>4</p>
              <p>5</p>
              <p>6</p>
              <p>7</p>
              <p>8</p>
              <p>9</p>
              <p>10</p>
              <p>11</p>
              <p>12</p>
              <p>13</p>
              <p>14</p>
              <p>15</p>
              <p>16</p>
              <p>17</p>
              <p>18</p>
              <p>19</p>
              <p>20</p>
              <p>21</p>
              <p>22</p>
              <p>23</p>
              <p>24</p>
              <p>25</p>
              <p>26</p>
              <p>27</p>
              <p>28</p>
              <p>29</p>
              <p>30</p>
              <p>31</p>
              <p>32</p>
              <p>33</p>
              <p>34</p>
              <p>35</p>
              <p>36</p>
              <p>37</p>
              <p>38</p>
              <p>39</p>
              <p>40</p>
              <p>41</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bg-dark text-info">
        right sidebar
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to keep the first col to master yje height of that row, the second has to be taken off the flow . an extra wrapper can be used to constrain the content to overflow once height is reached : https://jsfiddle.net/12Lo7ptg/  a min-height on the second column will be needed https://jsfiddle.net/12Lo7ptg/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works for wide screen but in your example the red section completely disapears on a small screen. I would like it to be displayed bellow the embeded video on small screens. Can this be corrected?

Comment: see second jsfiddle with the min-height value set to 40vh in the example, but use any value of your own , it should not be more than video's height.

Comment: This seems to work on all screen sizes https://jsfiddle.net/kru253xL/ not very ellegant but should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the scrollable content inside a `position:absolute` parent, and then set `overflow:auto` on the column. There are utility classes for this included in Bootstrap 4.3 and newer.

```
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10" id="video">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 overflow-auto bg-danger">
                            <div class="position-absolute">
                                <p>1</p>
                                <p>2</p>
                                ....
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/W0onIeqkRy

EDIT:

If you only want the scroll behavior on larger screen widths (md and up), you could use a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .position-md-absolute {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the scrollable portion now disapears entirely when the screen size is narrow. I would like it to appear bellow the embeded video as it did in my example.

Comment: Use a media query as explained